# Why is Jinja code not removed by HTML comments?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I just wasted an hour trying to debug something broken, and it turned out to be caused by the first thing I tried removing:

```
<!-- <foo>Some HTML with {% if bar.thisWillThrow() %}{{ "Jinja" }}{% endif %} </foo> -->
```

It turns out that with this HTML-style comment, `bar.thisWillThrow` is still called, which (as it was the cause of my problems) still threw an exception, leading me to believe that was not the problematic line.

I am aware of Jinja's `{# comments #}`, but I'm curious why this didn't work.

The only advantage I can think of is that this allows `<!-- {{ foobar.comments }} -->`, but I can't imagine why someone would want to keep their comments separate from their code, it sounds like a total nightmare! I also can't imagine the designers would want to encourage logging in comments.

What good does this behaviour do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja does not have that much knowledge about HTML to parse HTML comments. If you think about Jinja as a template engine for arbitrary text formats (not just HTML), this behavior makes total sense.

Comment: Oh I see it now, I don't understand how I missed it before! Obviously it's called, during the creation of the HTML document, and then any result is ignored when the browser hits the comment. D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's Jinja's function as a template engine. If you look up how a [template engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor) works, it says:

> A template processor (also known as a **template engine** or **template
>   parser**) is a piece of software or a software component that is
>   designed to combine one or more templates with a data model to produce
>   one or more result documents.

It converts whatever python data you give it into readable data.

Comment: Yes, readable as a string inside an HTML comment, then interpreted and rendered by a browser which ignores HTML comments.

Comment: @OllieFord That doesn't mean the HTML content suppresses the code entirely, just by looking at the source code you'll see the HTML with the respective comment.